# ImageView Not showing image after change visibility from gone to visible

Tags: java, android, imageview, visibility

I have this ImageView:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:id="@+id/formSuggestionScroll">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".SuggestQuestionActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpenGallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/suggest_btnOpenGallery"
    android:onClick="btnOpenGallery_click"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/buttons_paddingTop"/>

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/selectedPicContainer"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/imagen_dimen_width"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/imagen_dimen_height"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/image_padding"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:visibility="gone"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/suggest_send"
    android:onClick="btnSend_click"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/buttons_paddingTop"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to make it visible after user selects an image form gallery:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch(requestCode){

        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedPicContainer);


                imageUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap galleryPic = scaleBitmap(getPathFromUri(imageUri), view.getHeight());

                if(galleryPic != null){
                    view.setImageBitmap(galleryPic);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "selection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Code for scaleBitmap function:

```
private Bitmap scaleBitmap(String imagePath, int maxDimension) {

    Bitmap scaledBitmap;

    BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    op.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
    scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,op);

    if(maxDimension < op.outHeight || maxDimension < op.outWidth){
        op.inSampleSize = Math.round(Math.max((float) op.outHeight / (float) maxDimension,
                                              (float)op.outWidth / (float) maxDimension));
    }

    op.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,op);

    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

The problem is that the ImageView displays a color square, not the picture. The color depends on which image is chosen. So maybe something is wrong with the rendering but my knowledge about this is very small.

The problem dissapears if I set visibility to invisible instead of gone.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: you can move "view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" inside the onclick method where you are calling Galley.

Comment: What's the code behind the `scaleBitmap()` function?

Comment: Edited and added code for scaleBitmap(). thanks g00dy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that `view.getHeight()` is 0 because of it being `GONE`? So `scaleBitmap(getPathFromUri(imageUri), view.getHeight())` might be scaling it to 1 pixel?

Comment: That was the problem.Just to test, I sent 400 instead of view.getHeight() and worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u can also display a default image instead of making the view invisible